# c++11 shared_ptr doesn't handle `delete[]` properly: still detected memory leak

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, c++17, shared-ptr

I'm testing c++17 shared_ptr to see how it handles array delete[], but it failed expectation.

First, c++17 document says `shared_ptr<T[]>` can handle `delete[]` properly.

http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared#const-5

> Effects: When T is not an array type, constructs a shared_­ptr object that owns the pointer p. Otherwise, constructs a shared_­ptr that owns p and **a deleter of an unspecified type that calls delete[] p**.

And `reset()`:

http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared#mod-3

> Equivalent to shared_­ptr(p).swap(*this).

It will transfer the specification-required custom delete. So from my understanding, pre-c++17 I have to write like this:

```
shared_ptr<int> t1(new int[7], default_delete<int[]>());
```

Now it knows when 1st parameter is array type, compiler will generate call to `delete []`, so that we no longer have to specify delete function explicitly. I had a quick test on Ubuntu20.04 with clang++13:

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr<int> t1(new int[7], default_delete<int[]>());
    return 0;
}
```

Then `clang++ mytest.cpp && valgrind ./a.out`, no problem. But if I change to:

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr<int> t1(new int[7]);
    return 0;
}
```

Then `clang++ mytest.cpp -std=c++17 && valgrind ./a.out` will print:

```
==16407== Command: ./a.out
==16407== 
Father
1
==16407== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==16407==    at 0x483CFBF: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16407==    by 0x40450A: std::_Sp_counted_ptr<int*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (in /home/troskyv/a.out)
==16407==    by 0x4030A2: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (in /home/troskyv/a.out)
==16407==    by 0x403059: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (in /home/troskyv/a.out)
==16407==    by 0x403998: std::__shared_ptr<int, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (in /home/troskyv/a.out)
==16407==    by 0x4020C4: std::shared_ptr<int>::~shared_ptr() (in /home/troskyv/a.out)
==16407==    by 0x40152E: main (in /home/troskyv/a.out)
==16407==  Address 0x4db34c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 28 alloc'd
==16407==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16407==    by 0x4014F7: main (in /home/troskyv/a.out)
==16407== 
==16407== 
==16407== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16407==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16407==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 15 frees, 74,032 bytes allocated
==16407== 
==16407== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16407== 
==16407== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==16407== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

There's memory leak. So seems to me although I used `-std=c++17` option, shared_ptr still cannot handle `delete array` automatically.

Where did this get wrong?

Comment: `shared_ptr<int>` and `shared_ptr<int[]>` aren't the same thing. Look at the second line of your question. https://godbolt.org/z/KfE4efPEq

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `new[]` directly anyway. Use `std::make_shared()` instead: `auto t1 = std::make_shared<int[]>(7);`

Answer (score 1):

I see the answer is difference between `shared_ptr<int>` and `shared_ptr<int[]>`. Use of the latter one avoids memory leak.

Thanks, close this question!